# laravel ajax post serialize not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

```html
                    <form id="sendmemessage">
                            <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <h2 class="open-f bbold green-text contact-t">SEND ME A MESSAGE!</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-sm no-radius" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control input-sm no-radius" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control input-sm no-radius" placeholder="Subject">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control input-sm no-radius" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom pull-right btn-w">Send Message</button>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                    </form>
```

I am trying to subit the values of the form,i know this is just basic but i dont know why is not working.

below  is my ajax,

```
$("#sendmemessage").submit(function(stay){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ url('/') }}/message_me",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
           alert();
        },
    });
    stay.preventDefault(); 
});
```

my route

```
Route::post('message_me','home_controller@message_me');
```

my controller

```
class home_controller extends Controller{

    public function message_me(){

        echo "its here!";

    }

}
```

here are my form details code

Comment: Open developers console and check errors

Comment: POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/message_me 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Check your error logs to see error cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$(this).serialize()` was inside the ajax object and it refers to ajax not the form.

```
$("#sendmemessage").submit(function(stay){
   var formdata = $(this).serialize(); // here $(this) refere to the form its submitting
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ url('/') }}/message_me",
        data: formdata, // here $(this) refers to the ajax object not form
        success: function (data) {
           alert();
        },
    });
    stay.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: its not the full controller sir, i just put what important.

Comment: how to check storage/logs sir? im sorry but im just new in laravel

Comment: `this` in OP's code refers to the element `#sendmemessage`, whatever it is.

Comment: ya as its submitting now so its a form, in this case. please read the comment in the code.

Comment: i added my form please check sir,

Comment: @vincentvillafuerte replace `{{ csrf_field() }}` with  `<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: @vincentvillafuerte laravel uses csrf_token field name as `name="_token"` not `name="csrf_token"` i think

Comment: @RiazLaskar thank you sir! its just the name="_token", thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with replacing

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

with the helper function

```
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

I structure my ajax calls like the following:

```
$("#sendmemessage").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#sendmessage").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/message_me",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});
```

Can you access the "message_me" route via the browser? A 500 internal server error should give you clear insight why the request fails.